# Harmonic Conjugate (Multiplication, power, addition/subtraction)

Tags: harmonic-functions

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbIr4.png)

Suppose that $v$ is a harmonic conjugate for $u$ on a domain $D$. 
Prove that
$u(x,y)^3 - 3u(x,y)v(x,y)^2$ 
is harmonic.

I'm trying to prove that this function is also harmonic when $v$ is harmonic conjugate for $u$. 
I know that when this is the case, the function $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is analytic, and thus, $u+v$  or $uv$ are also harmonic. But I am not sure how to deal with the powers. Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $u$ is harmonic (and real valued) and $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $v$. Then $u + iv$ is analytic. Thus $(u + iv)^3$ is analytic. Thus the real part of $(u + iv)^3$ is harmonic. Because the real part of $(u + iv)^3$ equals $u^3 - 3uv^2$, we conclude that $u^3 - 3uv^2$ is harmonic.

Comment: Thank you!!! That really helps! I only thought about regular (a+b)^3 and didn't see that with i^2, it would make the second term negative. I did not see that! Thank you!